# Getting a page ID from MYSQL and displaying the content of that record

Tags: php, mysql

Okay guys i dont have any coding to show (sorry) what i need is php coding to do this

im currently creating a website that would host hundreds of pages game data like the image nam and description things like that, so instead of having to create hundreds of pages is there a way i could use 1 page to display different data

for instance the user wants gta iv so they click the link and it would give them the discription and name but then the user wants farcry so they click the link and it would display that information

is there a way using php and MySql to display different data using one page and in the url bar displaying mysite.com/index.php?PID=00001 (GTA IV DATA) or mysite.com/index.php?PID=00002 (Farcry)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please reformulate your question, as it's pretty hard to understand the way it is now.

Comment: would you mind to also include your code here.. for furhter illustration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$_GET`

```
mysite.com/index.php?PID=00001
```

to get the value of PID

```
$pid = $_GET['PID'];
```

now you have value of PID in variable $pid and clean it

```
$pid = mysql_escape_string($pid);
```

now use a query like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE pid = $pid";
```

execute the query and show results in your page

**sorry. i cant write full code for you. just a sample.**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['PID'])) {

  // Getting & cleaning value from url
  $pid = mysql_escape_string($_GET['PID']);

  // connection to your mysql
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "your_username", "your_password");
  $db = mysql_select_db("your_database", $con);

  // Getting data from table
  $query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE pid = $pid";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  // Checking weather we have results from table
  if (!empty($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      print_r($row);
      // do operations with your data
    }
  } else {
    echo 'no results';
  }
} else {
  echo 'no pid';
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry could you explain in a little more detail please?

Comment: im trying out your script but it aint working out for me im sorry im such a pest but could you give me everything that i would use to do what i said im no good with php once again sorry

Comment: Thanks very much this is what im looking for thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['PID'])) {

$employee = array('nina','simon','tom','zannel','bob');
foreach($employee as $key=>$e) {

if($key == $_GET['PID']) {
echo 'PID: '.$_GET['PID'].' Name: '.$e.' PHONE No: '.'00'.$key; }
    }
 }else {
echo 'Id is not found';

}
```

This is how it will display:

if you typed URL `index.php?PID=1`

> PID: 1 Name: simon PHONE No: 001

if you typed URL `index.php?PID=2`

> PID: 2 Name: Tom PHONE No: 002

if you typed URL `index.php?PID=2`

> PID: 3 Name: zannel PHONE No: 003

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a framework to develop this. I use [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) to develop pages like you're talking. It takes a lot of common things you would need to do with this site, and already does them. You worry mainly about how the information or data in your site interact.

The data is saved in a database with different fields, and CakePHP puts together the pages for you. You could have a table of sites. Each site in the table would have an Id, Name, a URL, a Manufacturer, etc. When a user visits somewebsite.com/sites/1, CakePHP puts together the site with Id 1.

Just an idea.